# JSF2: How to validate two dependent checkboxes?

Tags: jsf, validation, jsf-2

I have a form in JSF2 with 2 checkboxes (`<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`). At least one of them should be checked. Both checked are also ok, but when none is checked, there should be error.

This validation should work also on ajax, i.e. when user checks/unchecks, error message should disappear/appear.

So I binded both checkboxes to `UISelectBoolean` elements and added validator to each. In validator I check value of the second checkbox, if it is false, and current checkbox is also set to false, errormessage is produced. Smth like:

```
if (newValue == false && secondCheckbox.getValue() == false) {
  throw new ValidationException();
}
```

Problem is when user unchecks checkbox on the page, while the other is also unchecked, this false value doesn't go to the model, nor event to UISelectBoolean.

Scenario:

1. Initially both are unchecked
2. User checks checkbox1.
3. `newValue` is `true`, so this is valid, goes to UISelectBoolean and model.
4. User unchecks checkbox1. Checkbox2 is `false`, `newValue` is `false`, so exception is thrown.
   Because of failed validation, this `false` value doesn't go to the model, nor even to UISelectBoolean element.
5. User checks checkbox2. `True` value goes to the model and UISelectBoolean.
6. User unchecks checkbox2. Checkbox1 is still unchecked on the page, but in the model and UISelectBoolean there is still `true`. So validation passes and there is no error message. On the page both checkboxes are unchecked, but in model checkbox1 is still `true`.

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `<h:selectManyCheckbox required="true">`?

Comment: Yes, didn't know it :) Thanks!

Comment: Can I add <f:ajax> to <h:selectManyCheckbox>? Looks like f:ajax doesn't work.

Comment: See answer. Hint: to notify others about comment replies on posts which are not their own, use `@nickname`. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work Otherwise you're dependent on their eagerness to take a look back in the question at a later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `<h:selectManyCheckbox required="true">`. Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="options" value="#{bean.checked}" required="true">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" />
        <f:ajax render="optionsMessage" />
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    <h:message id="optionsMessage" for="options" />

    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" />
</h:form>
```

With

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<String> checked;
    private List<String> options = Arrays.asList("first", "second");

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("Checked: " + checked);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `f:ajax` works fine here. Probably you've used `event="click"` instead of (the default) `event="valueChange"` which will cause that the checkmark won't be retained after render. The `click` is namely called right before the checkmark get visually set. The render would block the checkmark being visually set.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC ! :) The only problem I have with it is that is creates a <table>, which I have inside <td> of another table. Than anything I put after this <h:selectManyCheckbox> element is displayed below checkboxes table. Is there any way to display it "after" table? I mean at the same level, to the right of checkboxes table.

Comment: Use CSS to set it to `display: inline;` or `float: left;`. Tomahawk's `<t:selectManyCheckbox layout="spread">` may also be helpful. You can position [`<t:checkbox>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_checkbox.html) everywhere you want. So, full control over markup.